# Chrome extension popup signin with Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to integrate Firebase with Chrome Extension that I'm currently developing.
In [Google's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#authenticate_with_firebase_in_a_chrome_extension) it says the following.

> The newer Manifest V3 only allows background scripts in the form of service workers, which cannot perform the popup operations at all.

Does it mean there is no possibility to show the popup window to the user from which he can select an account to connect with the service? If so, how the connection between Chrome Extension is established? I've tried to find some information on the web but it's still confusing to me.

Comment: Weird that this isn't asked more often!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome extension: Firebase Google sign in with AuthProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77472931/chrome-extension-firebase-google-sign-in-with-authprovider)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up triggering [launchWebAuthFlow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/identity/launchWebAuthFlow) in the background script which serves it's purpose well.

Comment: Note that this is only chromium compatible, which is fine if you plan to only have your extension available for chromium - which sounds obvious until you realize you can cross build to safari ext too

Comment: But how does that still allow you to do authentication with firebase? Especially if you want to only allow users with authenticated firebase creds to access firebase data.