# Chrome extension: Firebase Google sign in with AuthProvider

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

I created an auth provider:

```
  const authProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  authProvider.setCustomParameters({
    prompt: 'select_account',
  });
```

How can I use it to sign in with Firebase inside my Chrome extension? I cannot use `signInWithPopup` as the window object is undefined in extension context

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods to address this, but if you’re utilizing Manifest V3, I would suggest following my approach for the best user experience.

First, develop a standard web app where users can log in via the Google authentication provider or any other provider of your choice. After logging in, the token is sent to the Chrome extension, automatically logging the user into both the web app and the Chrome extension.

So, how is this accomplished? You’ll need a Firebase custom token, which must be generated on your backend. Given that you’re already using Firebase, I would advise utilizing Firebase cloud functions. In the web app, you request a custom token from your cloud function. Once you have the custom token, you can send it to your Chrome extension.

Here’s an example of how this might look in the web app:

```
// The cloud function is called:
const createCustomToken = httpsCallable(getFunctions(), "createCustomToken");
const token = await createCustomToken();

// The custom token is sent to the Chrome extension:
const response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage(<"your-extension-Id">, token);
```

It’s important to note that the user must be signed in when the above code is run is called. This can be accomplished using `signInWithPopup`, `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, or any other method of your choice.

And this is what the cloud function could look like:

```
exports.createCustomToken = onCall(async (request) => {
  const uid = request.auth.uid;
  const customToken = await admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid);
  return {token: customToken};
});
```

In the background script of your Chrome extension, you’ll have your Firebase authorization. Here, you can set up a listener for your web app to receive your custom token, as shown below:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (sender.url === <"https://your-web-app">) {
    signInWithCustomToken(getAuth(), request.data.token).then(() => {
      sendResponse("success");
    });
  }
});
```

Once `signInWithCustomToken` is called, your Chrome extension will also be signed in.

Remember, you need to add the URL of your web app to manifest.json as shown below:

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["https://your-web-app"]
},
```

Additionally, you need to enable the Identity and Access Management (IAM) API in Google Cloud. If it’s not enabled, you’ll likely receive an error message instructing you how to do so. You can also find more information about it at [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).